# Powershell ComboBox not displaying item

Tags: powershell

I have written an powershell cmdlet:

```
$comp = Get ADOrganizationl Unit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' FT Name, 'OU=Agencies,DC=state,DC=nv,DC=us -A'
```

This returns what want in a PS console however when I try to populate a Powershell Studio 2015 ComboBox with the following:

```
Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $combobox (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' | FT Name, 'OU=Agencies,DC=state,DC=nv,DC=us -A')
```

I get this:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
>      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
>      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

Repeated with the number of entrys...
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Load-ComboBox` Expect String or Array Objects.

Because you are using the Format-Table it Translate it to a `[FormatStartData,FormatEntryData and FormatEndData]` Object, while it's useful on the console for view purposes, it's not readable for the combobox, of course you can add the `| Out-String` at the end of your `$comp` line but i believe it's not the result you are looking for...

So if you only need the Name Property, use this:

```
$comp = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' | select -ExpandProperty Name
Load-ComboBox $combobox1 -Items $comp
```

And if you need the 'DistinguishedName' as well use this:

```
$comp = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' | select Name, DistinguishedName

foreach ($item in $comp)
{
    Load-ComboBox $combobox1 -Items ("$($item.name),$($item.DistinguishedName)") -Append
}
```